# How to get substring value from database?

Tags: php, mysql

How can we get the value from mysql database using this code in php?

code:

```
$query = "select substring(yr,1,4) from bday where id ='1'";
$sql=mysql_query($query);
$res = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

I tried this code `$res['yr']` to know its value but it gives me 'Array'.

How can i get its real value from mysql database?

Comment: can you debug your result using print_r($res) and try to do like $res[0]['yr']

Comment: now working @justrohu i forgot to put `as yr` on my query thanks anyway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql_fetch_array will fetch data as an array so you have to use indexes.

Try

```
echo $res[0]
```

or use an alias

```
$query = "select substring(yr,1,4) as yr from bday where id ='1'";
$sql=mysql_query($query);
$res = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

echo $res['yr'];
```

Dosc link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Note: Please try to use PDO or Mysqli.

PDO learning Links.

http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2h-sw9fZq0

Mysqli Learning tutorials:

http://codular.com/php-mysqli

http://www.phphaven.com/article.php?id=65

Comment: by the way @ThinkingWeb can you give me an instruction link on how to use PDO or mysqli thanks in advance

Comment: yes why not. in fact mysql_* function are deprecated and now recommended to use PDO or mysqli functions I am going to share some useful links here that you can use for future development.

Comment: Please see update i have added some links for PDO + Mysqli learning. Try it will be a good skill.

Answer (score 0):

Give alias to the value *substring(yr,1,4)* like :

```
$query = "select substring(yr,1,4) as sb_string from bday where id ='1'";
$sql=mysql_query($query);
$res = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

echo $res['sb_string'];
```